# Get all tags followings a certain with mechanize ? (ruby)

Tags: ruby, xpath, css-selectors, nokogiri, mechanize-ruby

How can I get all elements following once, like :

```
<div id="exemple">
  <h2 class="target">foo</h2>
  <p>bla bla</p>
  <ul>
    <li>bar1</li>
    <li>bar2</li>
    <li>bar3</li>
  </ul>
  <h4>baz</h4> 
  <ul>
     <li>lot</li>
  </ul>
  <div>of</div>
  <p>possible</p>
  <p>tags</p>
  <a href="#">after</a>
</div>
```

I need to detect `<h2 class="target">` and get all tags to the next `<h4>` and ignore `<h4>` **AND** all followings tags (if `<h4>` not exist, I have to get all tags to the end of parent [here : end of `<div>`])

**The content is dynamic and unpredictable** The only rule is : we know there is a target and there is a  (or end of element). I need to get all tags beetween both and exclud all others.

With this exemple I need to get the HTML following :

```
<h2 class="target">foo</h2>
<p>bla bla</p>
<ul>
  <li>bar1</li>
  <li>bar2</li>
  <li>bar3</li>
</ul>
```

so I can get : `target = page.at('#exemple .target')`
I know `next_sibling` method, but how can i test the type of tag of the current node?

I think about something like that to course the node tree :

```
html = ''
while not target.is_a? 'h4'
  html << target.inner_html
  target = target.next_sibling
```

How can I do this?

Comment: This is more of an [tag:XPath] or [tag:CSS-selectors] question than it is about mechanize. If you added those, you'd get a larger audience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subtract the ones you don't want from your nodeset:

```
h2 = page.at('h2')
(h2.search('~ *') - h2.search('~ h4','~ h4 ~ *')).each do |el|
    # el is not a h4 and does not follow a h4
end
```

Maybe it makes more sense to use xpath but I can do this without googling.

Your idea of iterating next sibling can work too:

```
el = page.at('h2 ~ *')
while el && el.name != 'h4'
    # do something with el
    el = el.at('+ *')
end
```

Comment: Thx, I don't know was so easy to get type of tag (use `.name`). My use case give this : `el = page.at('#Nom_commun').parent
    html = el.inner_html
    el = el.at('+ *')
    while el && el.name != 'h4'
      html << el.inner_html
      el = el.at('+ *')
    end`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to return the `h2` element and its following siblings. I'm not clear on whether you want to keep or discard the `h4`; if you want to keep it the XPath would be:

```xml
//h2[@class="target"] | //h2[@class="target"]/following-sibling::*
```

If you need to exclude the `h4`:

```xml
//h2[@class="target"] | //h2[@class="target"]/following-sibling::*[not(self::h4)]
```

**Edit**: If you need to exclude an `h4` and anything beyond:

```xml
//h2[@class="target"] | //h2[@class="target"]/following-sibling::*[not(self::h4) | not(preceding-sibling::h4)]
```

Comment: This isn't quite it, it needs to stop at the `h4`, not just exclude it.

Comment: I edited question, sry about imprecisions, but we can't know how many and the type of possible existing tags followings <h4>, so I need to ignore all tags since <h4> (included). I can't do a solid xpath cmd because the content is dynamic and unpredictable !

Comment: @Matrix You certainly can do it in XPath! See my edit.